# Chrome showing target link after event has been prevented

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#div1">link 1</a>
<a href="#div2">link 2</a>
<a href="#div3">link 3</a>
<a href="#div4">link 4</a>
<div id="div1">div 1</div>
<div id="div2">div 2</div>
<div id="div3">div 3</div>
<div id="div4">div 4</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
a{
    padding-left:20px;
}
div{
    background:cyan;
    margin:600px 0;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Here, even though the default *targeting* action is *prevented*, chrome still shows the target after the `a` tag has been clicked and I'm *not hovering* on the link (however, this *doesn't* happen in case of IE or Mozilla):

[image]

[**Check this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hg4m1p8o/).

how to solve this issue?

**EDIT:**

What I meant was - *the target is shown even when I'm not hovering on the link.*

Besides this, *it would give any non-technical user a false idea that the page is still loading*.

Comment: I think preventDefault just disables the event, it doesnt magically hide the actual url it is pointing to.

Comment: Tested in Chrome 38 and it's working fine, which version are you using?

Comment: @PabloRincon I added an edit, please check.

Comment: @theScorpion Try clicking on "Run" in JSFiddle. Same behavior on that "link"? Not your fault. When staying on the same page, Chrome keeps showing the link. That's not something to worry about.

Comment: I also can't replicate the issue you're talking about. It looks like preventDefault is doing its job correctly.

Comment: I have exactly the same behavior with IE, Mozilla, Chrome, you don't want the target to be showed when you hover over the link?

Comment: No, the issue is- target is being shown even I'm *not hovering* on the link.

Comment: It appears, that when unhovering a clicked link (default prevented) in Chrome, you've to focus another element before the URL tip goes away. Other browsers hide the tip just by unhovering.

Comment: @blex but isn't that a bit weird? It is kind of interfering with my modal window.

Comment: @PatrickLC  I'm using Version 39.0.2171.71 m

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be on any page, not just JSFiddle (at least on Chrome 39). If I click+drag a link, the status bar shows the URL until I click somewhere else. Is it a major issue to your UX?

Comment: @philtune It's interfering with a modal window.

Comment: besides this, *it would give any non-technical user a false idea that the page is still loading*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is native behaviour of the browser. It's displaying the URL because it is the href of the *active* link. The link remains active after being clicked because it has focus. If you want to make it inactive you could blur the element on click.

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.target.blur();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Although the URL will still remain visible while the link is hovered over.